# JQuery pagination with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I was wondering if anyone has come across a JQuery pagination script where a validation event can occur and if validation is successful then to load in the next page that was selected, else let JS Validator point out the errors and prevent next page from being loaded.
Basically I am writing some code that has a questionnaire type form and some fields require validation.

Currently I am playing with www.xarg.org pagination script and added in some code to allow validation to occur on various field elements but his code seems to trigger onFormat first before onSelect occurs (onSelect is where my validation kicks in) so although the error occurs on page 1, the link that you select next is highlighted which I am trying to avoid.

I have uploaded my code so far here (http://rkcr.recruitment.saint-dev.co.uk/form_stackoverflow.html) if anyone either could advise or recommend another solution.

Also, just a heads up that I am not a hardcore JS developer but hacking my through to make ends meet :-|

Thanks

Raj